# deeplink electron is thier any way on opening other pages using deep links

Tags: electron

I want to change from index.html to index2.html
if someone calls for `localm://okay`
currently, my application runs on deep link `localm://okay`

here is what my code looks like
i have tried many other ways but i am not able to fix this issue

````
 let deeplinkingUrl;

  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('localm');
  
  app.on('open-url', function (event, url) {
    event.preventDefault()
    deeplinkingUrl = url
  })
  
  
  //  M A I N   W I N D O W 
  let window
  
  app.on('ready', () => {
    window = new BrowserWindow({
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
      width: 1180,
      height: 768,
      minWidth: 1170,
      minHeight: 768,
      title: "LocalMiner",
      icon: __dirname + '/assets/logo.ico',
      titleBarStyle: "hidden",
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
      frame: false,
      titleBarOverlay: {
        color: "#1f2937a4",
        symbolColor: "#fff",
      },
      webPreferences: {
        // devTools: false,
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
        webviewTag: true,
      }
    })
    window.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/WEB/index.html');
    ipcMain.on("download", (event, info) => {
      // console.log(info);
      info.properties.onProgress = status => window.webContents.send("download progress", status);
      download(BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), info.url, info.properties)
        .then(dl => window.webContents.send("download complete", dl.getSavePath()));
    });
    LocalApi();
  })```

if we can achieve using anyway i will be really helpfull
````

Comment: So, you have tried "many ways". What exactly? Please show us your research by [edit]ing your question.